# JQuery/JS: Progressive cycling through array to show picture sequence, with input comparison from user

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, this is a bit complicated, at least for me. At first, I was making a Javascript game of Simon. Everything was working fine, until I realized that I never played Simon before. The rules of the game changed, and I had to recode my entire game.

Instead of showing a full sequence before each player's turn, I have to show bits of the sequence at a time before each player's turn. This is a huge problem for me, it seems. I've tried everything to get this to work correctly, but right now the only thing that happens is it gives me the alert messages (up to player1Turn() alert) until it goes haywire. This is extremely important for me to figure out, since it's a project.

It seems right now that the code doesn't record the player's input. I'll try to comment it as much as I can.

```
        function playButtonSequence(sequence) {
alert("playing sequence");
 // "sequence" contains originally generated random array.
 // it get shift()ed at end of function. so let game end if it's complete.
if (sequence.length < 1) {
    endGame();
}
 //sequenceCounter is a global var beginning at 1.
 //storedSequence is a slice() of sequence.
 //so far, this only shows the first element of the array. Good. 
if (sequence.length >= 1) {
    var i = 0; 
    while( i < sequenceCounter ) {
        $("#c" + storedSequence[i] + "i").attr("src", "imgs/" + storedSequence[i] + ".png");
        $("#snd" + storedSequence[i])[0].play();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#c" + storedSequence[i] + "i").attr("src", "imgs/d" + storedSequence[i] + ".png");
        }, gameMode.speed);
        i++;
         }
      }
    //shift the sequence for control purposes, iterate sequenceCounter, move onto player1's Turn!
   sequence = sequence.shift();
   sequenceCounter++;
    player1Turn();
}
  function player1Turn() {
 // Got the alert, we're in, at least. But no sound is played when I click a button (the functions for the buttons worked fine before. the arrays are not being compared. Why?
alert("Es turno del jugador uno!");
player1.active = true;
     if (player1.active === false && player1.sequence.length === sequenceCounter.length) {
    player2.active = true;
    player2Turn();
       }
         if (player1.active) {
         $("#c1i, #c2i, #c3i, #c4i").unbind();
            $("#c1i").on("click", function() {
        redButton();
        player1.sequence.push(1);
        player1.active = false;
         });
       $("#c2i").on("click", function() {
        yellowButton();
        player1.sequence.push(2);
        player1.active = false;
       });
         $("#c3i").on("click", function() {
        blueButton();
        player1.sequence.push(3);
        player1.active = false;
       });
       $("#c4i").on("click", function() {
        greenButton();
        player1.sequence.push(4);
        player1.active = false;
        });
     }
 }
```

Comment: simple review tip: use `console.log` instead of `alert` to debug your JavaScript code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this open-source version of Simon Says game for inspiration.

https://github.com/kellyk/javascript-simon/